# Cannot convert return expression of type 'PrimitiveSequence<SingleTrait, String>' to return type 'Observable<String>'

Tags: rx-swift

I am getting error 
Cannot convert return expression of type 'PrimitiveSequence' to return type 'Observable'

a Single returns PrimitiveSequence, so how can I convert it to Observable of type String?

```
return Single<String>.create(subscribe: { (single) in
    single(.success("test"))            
    return Disposables.create { }
})
```

What is right way - I have an API which will return String - say Token.

Answer (score 3):

Just tack on `.asObservable()`...

```
func foo() -> Observable<String> {
    return Single<String>.create(subscribe: { (single) in
        single(.success("test"))
        return Disposables.create { }
    }).asObservable()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe you should change your `func`'s return statement to `Single<String>`:

```
func getTest() -> Single<String> {
    return Single<String>.create { single in
        single(.success("test"))            
        return Disposables.create { }
    }
}
```